# Difference between 'vuotare' and 'svuotare'

Tags: verbs, difference

Is there a difference in context or connotation between the verbs 'vuotare' and 'svuotare', both meaning 'to empty'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verbs 'vuotare' and 'svuotare' indicate the same action and can be used both to define the action of emptying something, or in figurative sense (i.e. *In estate la città si svuota / vuota*)

[Here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svuotare/) you can find a definition of 'svuotare'. [Here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vuotare/) you can find a definition of 'vuotare'.

Comment: Why shouldn't you use *vuotare* in a figurative sense? You can indeed, and http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vuotare/ confirms this (“il suo discorso si è vuotato così d’ogni significato”).

Comment: @DaG: You're right. I've edited my answer

Comment: Joe, how did you edit the answer? I ask because I see you wrote almost nothing here.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis: Two vers are the same thing, and I've posted the link of Treccani. You think isn't it sufficient?

Comment: Joe, generally speaking, I think fuller answers are better than a one-line text.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis: I try to improve my answer.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis: Hi, I've update my answer, if is a poor answer I'll delete ;)

Comment: Joe, OK, I'm going to upvote.

Comment: `svuotare', as the link said, tends to give the idea of a completely empty object, ie it is 'intensivo'

Comment: @rano So perhaps we might consider “empty out” as a more precise translation for svuotare?

Comment: @fool4jesus exactly

Answer (score 7):

In my experience (native language speaker) *svuotare* is a bit stronger and less technical. Also, the initial 's' sounds almost onomatopoeic, giving a definite emphasis.

Comment: It is like _scancellare_ and _cancellare_: The starting S gives more emphasis.

Comment: _Scancellare_ is a bit weird though. Maybe formally correct, but you won't find it in a newspaper article.